# How to specify the order of class members when formatting in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse IDE how do you customize the Java code style formatter to have it sort the class members with a specified order, for example to group all instance methods by visibility?

Comment: I just asked a related question for sorting the members by their usage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485674/how-to-sort-methods-members-of-a-java-class-by-their-usage-in-eclipse

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the question is, "how do you customize the 'Source -> Format' command to re-order members?", I don't think it can be done. To change the order used for the 'Source -> Sort Members' command, change the "Members Sort Order" preference: "Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Appearance -> Members Sort Order"

Comment: It seems to me this only affects the sort order in viewers, e.g. an outline.  It does not reformat the source file.

Comment: This is the order that will be used if you do "Source -> Sort Members". "Source -> Format" does not re-order members AFAIK.

Comment: See user221156 answer, you need to use the Source > Clean Up... command.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure when they added this functionality, but it seems to be there in 3.5:

Window -> Preferences

Java -> Editor -> Save Actions

Additional actions -> Configure ...

Code Organizing -> Members -> Sort Members

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to perform a code Clean Up:

Setting sorting order:

1 - Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Appearance -> Members Sort Order - Check "Sort members in same category by visibility

2 - Window -> Preferences ... Java -> Code Style -> Clean up ... On code Organizing, select Sort Members

Clean up:

3 - On your java source, right click -> Source -> Clean up.