# Eclipse sort private static final fields before static methods

Tags: java, eclipse, code-organization

When I enable member sorting in Eclipse, it puts `private static final` fields after `static` methods. How do I get `private static final` fields at the top of the file above `static` methods? The member sort order is set to the default order where `static` fields appear above `static` methods and `private` appears above `package`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify the order of class members when formatting in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198177/how-to-specify-the-order-of-class-members-when-formatting-in-eclipse)

Comment: No. Even when I put the fields at the top, it forcefully puts them back at the bottom even though sort fields is disabled in Source > Sort Members.

Comment: If I were you I'd edit your question to specify that you did exclude the sorting of members. Else it will get closed as being a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your problem, I would say that you are using a version of Eclipse that has a bug (Eclipse Luna v4.4.0).

- Upgrading to Eclipse Luna v4.4.1 only partially fixes the problem.
- Upgrading to Eclipse Luna v4.4.2 should fix the problem (still unreleased at time of writing this post).

**Eclipse Bugzilla:** [Sort Members Bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=434941)

**Note:** *Normally, changing preferences in: "Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Appearance -> Members Sort Order" would be the fix.*