# How to sort methods/members of a Java Class by their usage in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

The book CleanCode recomments to sort functions by their call order:

> If one function calls another, they should be vertically close,
>   and the caller should be above the callee, if at all possible. This gives the program a natural
>   flow.

I would like to include that order in my cleanup routine. The following example

```
public void content(){
   primary();
   secondary();
}   

private void secondary(){

}

private void primary(){

};
```

should be automatically reordered to

```
public void content(){
   primary();
   secondary();
}

private void primary(){

};

private void secondary(){

}
```

(This is not the alphabetical order and primary() and secondary() have the same modifiers.)

However, I could not find an Eclipse feature doing so. Eclipse just seems to be able to sort members by their type and not by their usage.

Is there a default feature that I missed or an additional Eclipse plugin that I could install?

(I am not looking or an outline view that provides that order. I would like to change the actual order in the code. This question is not about the pros and cons of changing the code this way.)

Related article:

[How to specify the order of class members when formatting in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198177/how-to-specify-the-order-of-class-members-when-formatting-in-eclipse)

Comment: Thank you. I did not find that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of ProgrammersBlock I found this plugin in Beta status:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Recommenders/CleanCodeMethodSorter